# Source for the concept of learning 1 hour on Shabbat is like 1000 during the week?

Tags: shabbat, torah-study, shiurim-measurements, chol-weekday

There is a Benayahu on Taanit 11a I think that may hint to this, but not clear enough. Is there an actual source for "1 hour learning on shabbat is like 1000 hours during the week"?

Comment: The source is the Benayahu

Comment: [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6xKLI.png)
He never discusses the idea of 1-1000.

Comment: I don't think the source is a Zohar, because when he says Mekubalim it usually means the Ari. BN BH I'll look in the Ari. Thank you very much.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20203&st=&pgnum=58&hilite=

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ben Ish Chai  Shemot Shana Bet, the drasha at the beginning.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14054&pgnum=307) He states that the action you do in Torah on Shabbat is 1000 times greater than that action during the week.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard that the source of this Ben Ish Chai is a Zohar, however I have as of yet been unable to locate it.

The wording of the Ben Ish Chai is
על פי המקובלים, שהלימוד בשבת פועל פי אלף מהלימוד בימות החול

Comment: One time I was listening to a Devar Torah or a Shiur and the Magid Shiur was like maybe 30 years old, and someone said something to him and he quoted the Zohar, so they Maggid said "zeh lo katuv bazahor-it's not written in the Zohar." People may think that's arrogance, but he was telling the truth- a few months ago I learned that this young guy learned the entire Zohar, Talmud Babli and Yerushalmi as well as other books. =I think I will ask him this question even though I don't like to bother him too much.